# Rails to_xml add options to root node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have a Ruby hash in my code, that I'm converting to XML using `to_xml`.  Everything seems to be fine, except the API i'm sending requests to require options to be attached to the root node.  For example:

```
request = {
  "Header" => "", 
  "Body" => {
    "GetOrders" => {
      "workorderList" => {
        "string" => "value"
      },
      "clientID" => ENV['CLIENT_ID'], 
      "clientPassword" => ENV['CLIENT_PASSWORD']
    }
  }
}
```

Calling `to_xml` on this Ruby hash converts the XML as I would expect.  I pass a root option when I call `to_xml`.  However, how can I add options to the root node, so that instead of the root node looking like this (from `.to_xml(root: 'Envelope')`): `<Envelope>` it would look like this `<Envelope option="value">`.

I know there are other gems & XML builders, but I only need to be able to simply add these options to the XML's root node.

How can this be done quickly in Ruby & Rails?

Answer (score 2):

Rails `Hash#to_xml` does yield to a block:

```
request.to_xml do |options, key|
  # options[:builder] gives the builder for the node
end
```

But I think you are beyond the simple use case that this utility method was designed for.

While it is potentially possible to use this to add attributes it might be much simpler and more future proof to use a XML parser - Rails already includes [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html).

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(request.to_xml(root: 'Envelope'))
doc.at_css('Envelope')['options'] = "value"
doc.to_xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I try doing this, on the `document.at_css()` line I get back `undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Hm, did you try looking at the XML output to make sure there is a  `<Envelope>` element?

Comment: Technically it's `soapenv:Envelope`, but yes I did, and it's there.

Comment: If its namespaced then you need to use a different selector - anyways if you are doing SOAP then I would seriously consider using [Savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Tried Savon to no avail -- the API we are sending requests to whitelists IP addresses, and we're on Heroku.  I tried using Proximo to send via a static IP address, but couldn't get it to work with Savon.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there - you might wan't to look at the Nokogiri docs for how to deal with XML namespaces or construct a xpath selector.

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks @max